# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loggingIn'

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to configure the login for my Meteor app with the following code in the Router file.

```
if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
 return 'loading';
} else if (Meteor.user()) {
 return 'ecoData';
} else {
 return 'signin';
}
```

It was working fine until I tried to change my loading page to include an image and change where the signin page was. I now get the following errors even after changing it back to the original point.

```
/Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1zmhve++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loggingIn'
at app/router.js:23:12
at app/router.js:58:3
at /Users/me/Documents/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/jasonsigmon/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1zmhve++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/me/Documents/ecoportu/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
Exited with code: 8 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Still new to programming; so, I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shouldn't be running on the server:

`Meteor.loggingIn` is not available for use on the server. It's only available on the client.

Simply re-structure it so it runs in `if(Meteor.isClient) {` to solve the issue.

Comment: I wrapped all of the code in is(Meteor.is Client)  { code } . Now it says unexpected token { after (Meteor.isClient)

Comment: @jaysig Sorry there was a typo there i meant `if` not `is`. You're basically only running the code when its on the client.

Comment: Not a problem. The app now starts, but it just takes me an ironrouter landing page and will not allow me to access any pages. Thanks again for your help.